# Filling a Correlation Mirror Image

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

How would you flip a correlation matrix in R, so instead of having (na) values, it would have the identical correlations in the mirrored rows and columns? This might be explained better assisted with an image.

[Correlation Matrix in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO78j.png)

I've been trying the `complete.cases` command, however this does not seem to help my objective. Also `na.omit` does not do the trick, since I would then be left with only one row, namely the bottom row.

I've been copying the correlations manually in Excel to get the desired result, but this seems as a tedious procedure, especially if the correlation matrix is vast.

Please, do you guys have any quick fixes or smart mechanics for this sort of issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A correlation matrix in R is already symmetrical (e.g. `cor(mtcars)` . How are you producing your correlation matrix?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Check the code here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-an-r-function-to-do-all-you-need.  If you post a sample of your data somebody can give you a fuller answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlation matrix is already symmetrical in R by default. For example:

```r
cor_m <- cor(mtcars[1:5])

cor_m
#>             mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat
#> mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620 -0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.6811719
#> cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000  0.9020329  0.8324475 -0.6999381
#> disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000  0.7909486 -0.7102139
#> hp   -0.7761684  0.8324475  0.7909486  1.0000000 -0.4487591
#> drat  0.6811719 -0.6999381 -0.7102139 -0.4487591  1.0000000
```

However, it sounds as though you have a correlation matrix in this format for some reason:

```
cor_m[c(6, 11:12, 16:18, 21:24)] <- NA

cor_m
#>             mpg        cyl       disp         hp drat
#> mpg   1.0000000         NA         NA         NA   NA
#> cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000         NA         NA   NA
#> disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000         NA   NA
#> hp   -0.7761684  0.8324475  0.7909486  1.0000000   NA
#> drat  0.6811719 -0.6999381 -0.7102139 -0.4487591    1
```

To make this symmetrical, you would simply fill the cells which have NA values with the entries at the same positions of the transposed matrix:

```
cor_m[is.na(cor_m)] <- t(cor_m)[is.na(cor_m)]

cor_m
#>             mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat
#> mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620 -0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.6811719
#> cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000  0.9020329  0.8324475 -0.6999381
#> disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000  0.7909486 -0.7102139
#> hp   -0.7761684  0.8324475  0.7909486  1.0000000 -0.4487591
#> drat  0.6811719 -0.6999381 -0.7102139 -0.4487591  1.0000000
```

Comment: Hi Allan! Thanks for your reply. Apologies that I didn't mention this as I forgot, but this particular correlation matrix was imported from Excel. It had to do when importing files into R, which were incomplete as the one portrayed in my post. After I'd as.matrix() on the imported file, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much!